# "List of data sources" question

Tags: discussion, big-list, canonical-questions

Data requests are [off-topic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/should-we-allow-data-questions) on chem.SE.

Since two of them got asked today, I went back to look at that meta post. I'd like to revive two of the comments on the question:

> One difficult task is sometimes to find *where* appropriate data can be found, which is not always obvious or well referenced. I agree it is pointless to copy the values from the "Handbook of Chemistry & Physics", but sometimes finding relevant values is really a difficult task and might require some expert help." – PLD May 23 '12 at 20:54
>
> @PLD One solution to that might be a Community Wiki question/answer that list good places to find such values and MSDSes and so on. – Matthew Read Jul 10 '12 at 17:52

**Can we please have one such question on "where to find data"?** That way, we can close data requests as duplicates, exactly analogous to how book requests are closed as duplicates of the existing resource thread:

`Requests for specific data are [off-topic on Chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135). Please refer to the [linked duplicate](link to new question here) for a list of data sources which might help you find the information you need.`

If there are no objections, I will assume that we have consensus and go ahead with the creation of such a post.

Answer (score 5):

As with the other thread we should give it a lot of time to lay out the structure of such a list.

Objections are one thing, contributors another. The resources thread took more than a month to create and after we seemed to agree on how to do it and we proceeded to do it, there was a new discussion about how to organise it. The post itself is far from complete and has exactly those problems of big-lists, which make them a suboptimal fit for SE.

I am not completely against it, but it needs to be planned well ahead and then brought to a point where it is useful. And you'll need people for it. If it's incomplete you'll just open the door for questions saying

> I've tried all of that, but there was nothing.

There was once another attempt at a big list, very much rushed and it gained many down and close vote within the first few hours. I'm mobile and I can't look it up right now, and it was a bit forgettable in the first place.

I just want all to know the potential drawbacks with such an endeavour.

Comment: You can count on me as the BS (bureaucracy supervisor). I'll make sure it's organized perfectly.

Comment: Found it: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37425/4945